# Get Error Complex object error after check isStruct or isSimpleValue

Tags: coldfusion

I have a code to display message if upload process fails. The message variable can be a struct or a string. I've added code to check if the result is a struct or a simple value but I still get Complex object error. Is there anything that I missed?

Here is my code:

```
if (isStruct(result)) {
    if(StructKeyExists(result, 'messages')){
        theMessage = result.messages;
    }
}else{
    if(IsSimpleValue(result)){
        theMessage = result;
    }
}
FormMessage=getLang('CVLizerUploadFailed') & ' ' & getLang('PleaseContactYourAdmin') & ', ' & getLang('ErrorCode') & ' ' & theMessage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's simplify your code like below. It can be simplified further depending upon the earlier code, you need to look for it. The below code will check the type of result variable and depending upon type, it will set the value of theMessage variable.

```
 if (isStruct(result) AND StructKeyExists(result, 'messages')) {            
      theMessage = result.messages;                
   }
   else if (isSimpleValue(result){
      theMessage = result;                   
   }
```

There is nothing wrong with the code you wrote or simplified code. I can not say for sure that if there is wrong with last line of code as i do not have enough information on it.

Use **writedump and abort** immediately below and above the if condition code block in both cases when result is a struct and a variable to check when error occures. It's either the last line or any other line of code above this block of code.

Comment: i've check the variable, it turns out the variable returned from a function before is a struct where it should be a string (so result.messages is a struct, not a string). thanks for simplifying my code.